# Need help understanding part of the logic for a rewrite solution of the javascript reverse method?

Tags: javascript

So I was trying to understand this solution of rewriting the Array reverse method from scratch:

```
Array.prototype.reverse = function() {
  for(var i = 0, j = this.length-1; i < j; i++, j--) {
    var tmp = this[i];
    this[i] = this[j];
    this[j] = tmp;
  }
  return this;
 };
```

So I understand j starts as the amount of array elements - 1, and i is initially 0.  And then I believe they are both incremented or decremented by 1 until i is no longer less than j..What I don't understand is the following lines:

```
    var tmp = this[i];
    this[i] = this[j];
    this[j] = tmp;
```

Could anyone anyone what is going on in these lines?

Comment: Its a swap of element at `i` th position with the element at `j` th position.

Comment: it's swapping the value at index i with the value at index j to reverse the values in the array. using the tmp variable allows you to hold the value without overwriting it when you set i with the value of j

Comment: Ok thank you.  Should I delete the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's work through it with an example:

```
// assume `this` = ["a", "b", "c"]
// assume i = 0 and j = 2

var tmp = this[i];
// tmp:  "a"
// this: ["a", "b", "c"]

this[i] = this[j];
// tmp:  "a"
// this: ["c", "b", "c"]

this[j] = tmp;
// tmp:  "a"
// this: ["c", "b", "a"]
```

Notice that step two is `[c,b,c]` and the `[a]` is totally gone. This is why we save it to tmp, so that we can put it back in step three.